# Why dosen't my for each loop return anything?

Tags: java, foreach

The purpose of my code is to have the user input the name of a car. The code will use a for loop to search through an array list and print out the car that the user typed in. The code compiles, but it doesn't print anything out. Here is the code:

```
public class searchList
{  
    private static inventory inventory = new inventory();
    private static ArrayList<engineSpecs> list = inventory.getList(); 
    public void searchList()
    { 
        //Declarations
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String search = new String();
        String car = new String();

        //Prompts user to enter car name        
        System.out.println ("Enter car name: ");    
        car = scan.nextLine();

        //Searches array list and prints car
        for (engineSpecs item: list)
        {  
            if (item.equals(car))
            {
                System.out.println (item);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

The array list is declared in another class. Here is that class:

```
 public class inventory
 { 
    public static ArrayList<engineSpecs> list = newArrayList<engineSpecs>();
    public inventory()
    {                                                   
        //Adds objects into array list
    engineSpecs astonmartin = new engineSpecs("Aston Martin", "Vanquish", 350000, 11, "Gray",
                                     2015, 565, 457, "automatic");
    engineSpecs ferrari = new engineSpecs ("Ferrari", "458 Italia", 240000, 13, "Red", 2015, 
                                       570, 398, "automatic"); 
    list.add(astonmartin);
    list.add(ferrari);   
    }
    public static ArrayList<engineSpecs> getList()
    {
        //getter method
        return list;
    } 
}
```

My engineSpecs class is just a simple constructor. I'm using it so I can instantiate an object of this constructor and save it into the array list.

```
public class engineSpecs
{
    private int HP;
    private int torque;
    private String transmission;
    private int year;
    private int MPG;
    private int price;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private String manufacturer;
    public engineSpecs (String manufacturerName, String modelName,int stickerPrice, int MPGe,
    String extColor, int yearNum, int BHP, int torquelbs, String transmissionType) 
    {
        HP = BHP;
        torque = torquelbs;
        transmission = transmissionType;
        year = yearNum;
        MPG = MPGe;
        price = stickerPrice;
        model = modelName;
        color = extColor;
        manufacturer = manufacturerName;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "Manufacturer: " + manufacturer + "\n";
        result += "Model: " + model + "\n";
        result += "Price: " + price + "\n";
        result += "Estimated MPG: " + MPG + "\n";
        result += "Color: " + color + "\n";
        result += "Year: " + year + "\n";
        result += "Horse power: " + HP + "\n";
        result += "Torque: " + torque + "\n";
        result += "Transmission: " + transmission + "\n";

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you overused static keyword ?

Comment: How could an `engineSpecs` equal a `String`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp good point I wanted to ask whether is any data field in inventory class or not?

Comment: Can you post the code for `engineSpecs` class?

Comment: @seanConnery I think in your case you may need to use contains function to see if your list contain what you are looking for or not and I do not think for loop will be needed at that point

Comment: how can you add stings to a list of engineSpecs ? and why all these static fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using `.equals()` for objects which is not going to return true until they are same object in the memory. You need a new method that compares the string value of the name. Also you need `toString()` method to print the string conversion of the object.

Your engineSpecs class should look something like this:

```
public class engineSpecs{
    public String name;
    public engineSpecs(String s){
        this.name = s;
    }

    public boolean is(String car){
        return this.name.equals(car);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Update:

change your if statement to :

```
if (item.is(car))
{
    System.out.println (item);
}
```

Define this method in `engineSpecs` :

```
public boolean is(String manufacturerName){
    return this.manufacturer.equals(manufacturerName);
   //  need to compare more values if you want to compare more properties
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to redefine the method `equals()` in your class `engineSpecs`, so the line `item.equals(car)` works correctly.

More info [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/).

Comment: No, he shouldn't. At least, not `equals(Object obj)`, because that would break its contract. It should only return true for objects of the same type.